# Multiple images to page using php Facebook sdk shows unpublished

Tags: php, facebook

I had an auto page post script which send batch image uploads to Facebook and show as single status on my page's wall. I used PHP Facebook sdk version 5 . It was working earlier . Now I can see all images nd status added are showing in timeline for the page owner only, not to other users . Looks like it is in unpublished stage . Any recent changes to graph api ? How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Check if your app is still set to live/public in app dashboard.

Comment: App is in Development Mode

Comment: You need to set it live, otherwise all content created through it will only be visible to people with a role in the app.

Comment: Okay, Thank you , i will check it ..